# Is Meteor running from the wrong path?

Tags: meteor

I have just installed Meteor from the auth branch. Meteor seems to read its content from **/usr/lib/meteor** - But it was installed to **/usr/local/meteor**. **/usr/local/meteor/packages** contains all packages i need but when i list packages from terminal it shows the default ones. I'm trying to run a project i recently created on another computer:

```
Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: The package named accounts-ui does not exist.
at _.extend.init_from_library (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/packages.js:91:13)
at Object.module.exports.get (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/packages.js:225:11)
at self.api.use (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:83:28)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:76:11)
at Object.self.api.use (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:82:9)
at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use] (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/packages.js:136:11)
at _.extend.use (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:362:11)
at Object.exports.bundle (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:649:12)
at exports.run.restart_server (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:509:26)
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

My first thought was that some 'Meteor-path-variable' was set wrong, but i cant find something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Restarted the computer..